# How can i make a suffixIcon in a TextField which hides if TextField is empty but shows when not and toggles a bool to hide and show password?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I have a TextField() for a Password Input. The sufficIcon, which is an eye, should only be shown, when TextField is not empty but it should also toogle a bool, so that user can hide and show password. It should show different suffixIcon, when password is shown or hidden.

This is my code for now:

```
bool isPasswordVisible = true;

IconButton(
          icon: isPasswordVisible
              ? const Icon(Icons.visibility)
              : const Icon(Icons.visibility_off),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible;
            });
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:
Declare a boolean variable:

```
bool isIconVisible = false;
bool hidePassword = true;
```

then in the TextField use the property `onChanged`:

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (value) {
     //try this
     value.isNotEmpty ? setState(() => isIconVisible = true) : setState(() => isIconVisible = false);
     //or
     setState(() => value.isNotEmpty ? isIconVisible = true : isIconVisible = false);
     //the result is the same it's just a shortcode
  },
  obscureText: hidePassword,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Password',
        suffixIcon:  isIconVisible ? IconButton(
             onPressed: (){
                    setState(() => hidePassword = !hidePassword);
                    },
             icon:  Icon(
                  hidePassword ? 
                  Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                    ),
       ) : null,
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
bool hidePassword = true;
bool hidePasswordConfirm = true;
String? confirmPassword;
```

Now in the `TextFormField` widget :

```
TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    obscureText: hidePassword,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Password',
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          hidePassword
                              ? Icons.visibility_off
                              : Icons.visibility,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            hidePassword = !hidePassword;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (val) {
                      confirmPassword = val;
                      if (val != null) {
                        if (val.length <= 6)
                          return 'Password must be 6 characters.';
                      } else
                        return null;
                    },
                  );
```

Now for password confirmation :

```
TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Confirm Password',
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          hidePassword
                              ? Icons.visibility_off
                              : Icons.visibility,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            hidePasswordConfirm = !hidePasswordConfirm;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    validator: (val) {
                      if (val!.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Enter the password first';
                      } else if (val != confirmPassword)
                        return 'Password must be same.';
                      else
                        return null;
                    },
                    obscureText: hidePasswordConfirm,
                  );
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is about the confirmPassword?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code...

obscureText property in TextFormField used to show and hide the text inside textField.

In the Icon onPress we can change the bool value and UI using SetState to manage

```
bool _isObscure = true;
final _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();
final _focusPassword = FocusNode();

               TextFormField(
                    controller: _passwordTextController,
                    focusNode: _focusPassword,
                    obscureText: _isObscure,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                        iconSize: 23.0,
                        icon: Icon(
                          _isObscure
                              ? Icons.visibility_sharp
                              : Icons.visibility_off_sharp,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: const Color.fromRGBO(255,255,255,1),
                      hintText: 'password',
                      counterText: "",
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0, 
                      horizontal: 20.0),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(210, 248, 248, 1)),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                        errorBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 3,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0,1)),),
                      focusedErrorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 3,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0,1),
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(128,128,128,1),
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontSize: 14.0),
                    ),
                  ),
```

when obscureText is true

[image]

when obscureText is false

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To update your widget icon in your password text filed as the user types, try something like this.

Note, you will need **another text controller** with the initial user input password and you will need to declare a boolean called '**passwordMatch**' in your widget build for this to work.

```
// confirm password textfield with Icon
TextFormField(
  controller: _confirmpasswordController,
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: 'Password',
    suffixIcon: passwordMatch
        ? Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green)
        : Icon(Icons.check),
  ),
  onChanged: (value) {
    if (value == _passwordController.text.trim()) {
      setState(() {
        passwordMatch = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        passwordMatch = false;
      });
    }
  },
),
```